# xslt: sum up just a for of an integer array

Tags: arrays, xslt, xpath, sum, xquery

So, I have an array of integers. And I want to sum it up. But not the whole array but just till a position in the array specified by another variable.

For example. This beeing my array:

```
<xsl:variable name="myArray" as="xs:int*">
<Item>11</Item>
<Item>22</Item>
<Item>33</Item>
<Item>44</Item>
<Item>55</Item>
<Item>66</Item>
<Item>77</Item>
<Item>88</Item>
</xsl:variable>
```

And this beeing my position variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="myPosition" as="xs:int*">3</xsl:variable>
```

I expect the result 66.
(Because: $myArray[1] + $myArray[2] + $myArray[3] = 11 + 22 + 33 = 66)

Sounds rather simple but I can't find a solution.

I guess, I need the "sum" function and the "for" and "return" expressions. But I must admit didn't understand any of the examples and instructions I found corncerning these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you are using XSLT 2.0 since in your sample xslt are some constructs not supported in xlst 1.0. Therefore it should be easy as far as you can declare [Temporary trees](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#dt-temporary-tree).

I think you can do it very simply in this way `<xsl:value-of select="sum($myArray[position() &lt;= $myPosition])" />`

Comment: Yes, I use XSLT 2.0 Sorry for not inlcuding this information! Works well!

Answer (score 0):

This XSL template should work when applied to any XML input. It uses an EXSLT extension function [exlst:node-set](http://www.exslt.org/exsl/functions/node-set/) to convert your variable into a node-set.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:variable name="myArray" as="xs:int*">
        <Item>11</Item>
        <Item>22</Item>
        <Item>33</Item>
        <Item>44</Item>
        <Item>55</Item>
        <Item>66</Item>
        <Item>77</Item>
        <Item>88</Item>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="myPosition" as="xs:int*">3</xsl:variable>

    <!-- Converts the myArray variable (a result-tree fragment) to a node-set and then sums over all those in positions up to and including myPosition value. -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="sum(exslt:node-set($myArray)/Item[position() &lt;= $myPosition])"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can see it in action [here](http://www.xmlplayground.com/9cCsbV).